# I have one button in fragment and textbox in main activity. now if i press button in fragment some message will print in textbox . How to do it?

Tags: android-fragments

I have one Button in fragment and Textbox in main activity. Now if I will press button from fragment, some message will print in Textbox. How to do it?

public class MessageFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

```
public buttonPress press;

public interface buttonPress {
    void getText (String inputText);
}

private Button button;
public MessageFragment(){}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_message, container);
    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    press.getText("Received from fragmnet");
      }
```

}

Comment: So both fragment and textbox is in main activity??if yes then it is easy,you can use settext() in onclick() for the textbox